# ¿Son utiles los Constructors de Java?

Tags: java, constructor

Según entiendo los constructores de Java sirven para asignarle un valor a los elementos de una determinada clase, pero yo puedo asignarle esos valores a los elementos en esa misma clase sin necesidad de hacer un constructor.

De que sirve hacer esto:

```java
public class Main {
    int n;
}

public Main (){ // esto es un constructo
    n = 100;   
}
```

Si puedo hacer esto:

```java
public class Main {
    int n = 100;
}
```

¿En qué caso debo aplicar un constructor?¿Debo aplicarlo siempre?¿Da mayor legibilidad y entendimiento al código?

Comment: Eh, los constructores se usan para instanciar las clases. Si tú no declaras uno, Java de todas formas te da uno por defecto.  Por mucho que le des un valor por defecto a n en tu ejemplo, ¿cómo consigues una instancia de esa clase Main?

Comment: Simplemente debes usar un constructor si el valor de las propiedades del objeto van a cambiar, si no es así, no es necesario definir un constructor.

Comment: Recuerdo haber visto una pregunta como esta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Un constructor es un método especial que sirve para inicializar objetos. Se llama al constructor cuando se crea un objeto de una clase y se puede utilizar también para establecer valores iniciales para los atributos del objeto.**

Por lo tanto, si no necesitas modificar nunca el valor de su variable `n`, no es necesario definir un constructor:

```
 public class Main {
     int n = 100;
 }
```

pero, en cambio, cuando pudiera ser necesario inicializar el valor de `n` con diferentes valores, lo recomendable es definir un constructor para este objetivo.

```
public Main(int valorN) {
  this.n = valorN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Un constructor sirve para inicializar el objeto y establecer sus propiedades y valores predeterminados. Tiene el mismo nombre que la clase y no cuenta con ningún valor de retorno, ya que su función principal es inicializar el objeto y no devolver ningún valor. Además, un constructor puede aceptar argumentos, lo que permite configurar el objeto con valores específicos al momento de su creación.

Un constructor en Java tiene el mismo nombre que la clase a la que pertenece, y no posee un tipo de retorno explícito, lo que significa que no se utiliza la palabra clave void ni ningún otro tipo de datos para especificar el valor de retorno del constructor.
Por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos una clase Persona con los campos nombre y edad. Podemos definir un constructor para la clase Persona:

```java
public class persona {
String nombre;
int edad;

    public persona(String nombre, int edad) {    
    this.nombre = nombre;    
    this.edad = edad;    
    }
}
```

Para mas información puedes leer [este blog](https://blog.hubspot.es/website/que-es-constructor-java#:%7E:text=Para%20qu%C3%A9%20sirve%20un%20constructor,y%20no%20devolver%20ning%C3%BAn%20valor.) donde encontraras mas ejemplos.

Answer (score 0):

¿Y si en lugar de 100 quieres que `n` tenga otro valor, dependiendo de algún otro parametro (constructor parametrizado)?

```java
public Main(int valorInicialDeN) {
  this.n = valorInicialDeN;
}
```

Los constructores también pueden ser sobrecargados como otros métodos. ¿Y si quisieras tener varios constructores dependiendo de los datos que tengas?

```java
public Main(int valorInicialDeN) {
  this.n = valorInicialDeN;
  this.esEspecial = false;
}

public Main(int valorInicialDeN, boolean esEspecial) {
  this.n = valorInicialDeN;
  this.esEspecial = esEspecial;
}
```

Puedes encadenar los constructores también:

```java
public Main(int valorInicialDeN) {
  this(valorInicialDeN, false); // Este constructor llamará al de abajo
}

public Main(int valorInicialDeN, boolean esEspecial) {
  this.n = valorInicialDeN;
  this.esEspecial = esEspecial;
}
```